# How to get pixel coordinates in QGIS georeferenced output map?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, pixel

using the *QGIS* **Georeferencer GDAL** plugin, I can select **GCPs** (ground control points) on a map (*plain raster input map image* in a format like PNG or TIF) in an *unknown projection and boundaries*, and specify the coordinates for those points in my desired output projection; then the Georeferencer plugin can reproject the map image from the unknown input projection into the specified output projection, epsg:4326 in this case:
(each GCP is the **x,y** coordinate pair of a pixel in the input image followed by the **lon,lat** coord of that pixel on the map in the *desired target projection*)

```
    gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -gcp 738.445 571.363 -5.3664 39.8004 ...[lots of gcps]... -gcp 656.449 529.382 -5.2034 40.4102 inputmap.png  tmpmap.tif

    gdalwarp -r near -order 2 -co COMPRESS=NONE  tmpmap.tif  outmap.tif
```

When the input image with its ground control points is reprojected into the output image, the GCPs are reprojected too, and shown at their correct new locations.

Is there a programmatic way to obtain the pixel coordinates of the GCPs in the reprojected output image?
And more generally, is there a way to reproject a single point/coordinate pair from an unknown projection into a known specified projection, using GCPs to define the unknown projection like in the above commands?